# What does "scientific merits" in a job application mean?

Tags: application, job-search, terminology, finland

In a job application I should add a description of my "tieteellisistä ansioista", which translates to "scientific merits". (The application is only available in Finnish, in which I am fluent.)

The application also asks for information concerning my research and research interests; all of this is to be provided in the same document.

What, exactly, does "scientific merits" mean and cover in this context?

Answer (score 7):

It seems the use of "scientific merits" (and obviously especially the Finnish version of it) in a CV or application is specific to Finnish academic culture.

"Scientific merits" can be applied to a study, but [the meaning of it](http://solutionsirb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Who-cares-about-scientific-merit-.pdf) there is hard to apply to a person.

I found its use in a [Finnish application](http://www.kemi.uu.se/digitalAssets/200/a_200490-f_andreasorthaber_presentationofscientificmerits.pdf), where it is used as a title for "publications, teaching and student supervision and awards". So basically it could also be called "accomplishments" or "proven experience".

The linked example was the only actual use in a CV I could find (quickly). Of course, it is a single example, so I could be very wrong about my assumption this makes it part of "Finnish academic culture" more than general use.

Comment: I'm also not able to provide a general answer, but this is exactly the context I (a native Finnish speaker) have seen it used in before. In particular skewed towards awards and grants and such.